# How to merge two formulas into one?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Some expert can transform these two formulas into just one...

formula 1

```
=ArrayFormula(unique(SE(G2:G11<0;"";SE(A2=A2:A11;MAXIFS(F2:F11;A2:A11;A2);F2:F11))))
```

formula 2

```
=ArrayFormula((PROCV(I1:I5; SORT(SE(G2:G11<0;A2:G11);6;VERDADEIRO);6;0)))
```

**a copy of the spreadsheet here below to test**

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LtIEhB3amOfGNpDVLaWhRybdIKBehZPvGl8rowbX9oY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(I1:I10; 
 {SORT(FILTER(A2:F11; F2:F11< TODAY()); 6; ); 
  SORT(FILTER(A2:F11; F2:F11>=TODAY()); 6; 1)}; 6; )))
```

[image]